# Magento 2.3.4 email not send sometimes when order is placed or when change status

Tags: order-email, magento2.3.x

I'm using Magento 2.3.4 on siteground server, when I place an order, the confirmation email sometimes is sent and sometimes not, can someone tell me why?

Comment: Could it he the case that sometime the email isn't received? Have you checked https://www.mail-tester.com/

Comment: my score is 1.4/10 @DominicXigen do you know how can i improve it?

Comment: Yikes. That's a really low score. The score summary should give you suggestions how to to improve score. You should try and get around 8.